# windows phone : no trigger in xaml?

Tags: xaml, triggers, windows-phone-8

I don't know how to use triggers in xaml of windows phone 8.

But I have seen some people do it, like below:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Header="Background"
                                ExpansionMode="FullscreenOnly"
                                Template="{StaticResource ListPickerControlTemplate}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Buildings.ObjectList}"
                                Margin="0"
                                x:Name="buldings"
                                Padding="0">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding Path=BuildingSelectionCommand}"
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=buldings}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

But I don't have System.Windows.Interactivity.
And I failed to find a compatible package through Nuget.

Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Right click on References -> Add Reference.. -> Extensions -> Select
>   System.Windows.Interactivity

The assembly resides here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\Windows
>   Phone\v8.0\Libraries\

Comment: Right click on References -> Add Reference.. -> Extensions -> Select Behaviors SDK(XAML) for Wiin 8.1(Universal apps)