# Windows phone 8 checkbox image on check uncheck

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, checkbox, windows-phone-8

I have a grid with checkbox on top right of the grid. I want to specify the images to the checkbox when status change. When it is clicked I want to set the tick.png image to the checkbox. When I uncheck it I want to set blank.png image to it. How can I specify the images to this checkbox below?

```
 <ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="BookCategories" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>                   
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel ItemHeight="200" ItemWidth="200" Margin="10"/>                 
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="#12161e"  Opacity="0.5" Margin="10,-5,0,20" Tap="Grid_Tap_1" Height="200" Width="200">
                        <CheckBox  Grid.Row="1"  Margin="145,-15,-15,0" x:Name="Chkcategories" IsChecked="{Binding Path=BookCategoriesStatus, Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <Image Source="Assets/books.jpg" Height="30" Width="30"/>
                        </CheckBox>
                        <TextBlock  Margin="40, 80, 0, 0" FontSize="22" Text="{Binding Path=CategoryName}"></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ListBox>
```

Comment: Would it be suitable to add a converter in that image - something like bool to imagesource. The image will be depend then on checkbox status.

Comment: ok so where to specify the image source because the above image source is having no effect on the appearance? or the above image source code is fine by you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example - you can bind ImageSource to IsChecked value - to do this you will have to use a converter:
In xaml:

```
...
xmlns:common="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"
...
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <common:BoolToImageSource x:Key="converter"/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
...
<CheckBox x:Name="Chkcategories" >
     <Image Height="30" Width="30" Source="{Binding ElementName=Chkcategories, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource converter} }"/>
</CheckBox>
```

In .cs:

```
public class BoolToImageSource : IValueConverter
{
  public System.Windows.Media.ImageSource FalseValue;
  public System.Windows.Media.ImageSource TrueValue;


  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
     TrueValue = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Resources/tick.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
     FalseValue = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Resources/blank.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

     if (value == null)
        return FalseValue;
     else
        return (bool)value ? TrueValue : FalseValue;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
     return value != null ? value.Equals(TrueValue) : false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you want "First case" or "Second case" (look at the image and check this **[sample](http://sdrv.ms/1joIYT4)**).

[image: CheckBox sample]

In the first case you have to edit `CheckBox` template.
In the second case you can use only `DataTrigger` or [`Converter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20116311/1136101).

```
<CheckBox
    x:Name="checkBox"
    IsChecked="{Binding Path=BookCategoriesStatus, Mode=TwoWay}">

    <Image
        Height="30"
        Source="/Icons/circle.png"
        Width="30">

        <i:Interaction.Triggers>

            <ei:DataTrigger
                Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=checkBox}"
                Value="True">

                <ei:ChangePropertyAction
                    PropertyName="Source"
                    Value="/Icons/cross.png" />

            </ei:DataTrigger>

            <ei:DataTrigger
                Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=checkBox}"
                Value="False">

                <ei:ChangePropertyAction
                    PropertyName="Source"
                    Value="/Icons/circle.png" />

            </ei:DataTrigger>

        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    </Image>

</CheckBox>
```

Comment: I think your solution will be much easier :) He will only have to remember to add reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962346/windows-phone-no-trigger-in-xaml

Answer (score 0):

you can easily implement on onclick event

in On click event

> if(checkbox clicked){ chkbox.background = tick image }
>   else{
>   chkbox.background = untick _image
>
> }